# iOS UICollectionView Unexpected behavior on push to refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm try to implement push to refresh on my collectionView, the code is it.

```
private lazy var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let control = UIRefreshControl(frame: frame)
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getAllJobs), for: .valueChanged)
    return control
}()

collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

[image]

Comment: explain the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set frame for `UIRefreshControl`

I usually implement it using the following steps:

#### In class properties block:

```
let refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

#### In `viewDidLoad`:

```
collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadData), for: .valueChanged)
```

### Somewhere in class body:

```
// Refresh handler
@objc func loadData() {
        // Your refresh-code here
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. Sometimes there is refresh control flicker bug (somehow similar to yours). It can be solved by adding: `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` to your `viewDidLoad()` method.